# apache folder access restriction

Tags: apache

is there a way to restrict folder access in apache?

For example user X and Y alone should be able to access link myserver/files/101/

in browser and user Z should get 401 and similarly user Z alone able to access link  myserver/files/102/

where 101 and 102 are folders.

please guide me on this if possible.

thanks in advance

Comment: research on .htaccess. Sorry i couldn't provide you any more information because i'm not very familiar with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using user authentication here is the link http://www.apacheweek.com/features/userauth